# Latency in Kafka Streams Applications

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, fraud-prevention

We have a realtime fraud detection app and I am proposing using Kafka Streams to implement the solution.
One of the main concerns for us is the Latency, and using Kafka Streams could add more latency when processing events end to end.
This opinion is based on the idea that we need to read and write back to Kafka topics multiple times before we reach the latest stage and take an action against an attacker.

How is your experience with Latency with Kafka Streams?
Does adding more instances from your app could reduce the latency?

Comment: Sure, adding more instance will minimize lag, but if the producer is faster than your consumer, it cannot be prevented, since you cannot have more consumers than topic partitions.

Comment: I think your answer is in general for Kafka, but my question is specific to Kafka streams and writing back to Kafka then doing later processing.

Comment: The same logic applies to Kafka Streams. It is also limited in the number of threads/instances it can run to reduce lag/latency since it is built on top of the Consumer API like any other client